# Is analytics available with the MobileFirst Platform CLI developer edition?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I have installed the MobileFirst Platform CLI developer edition from https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/install/#clui

I am trying to investigate the analytics of the application, but this doesn't seem to be properly installed from here.

I am able to create a MFP server, start it and access the console.  It doesn't have a link to the analytics in the top-right of the console as it does in the developer edition provided by Eclipse.  Is this behaviour as expected or is there something missing?

I have tried installing this package twice.  I am running on OSX 10.10

In the Liberty servers directory, /Users//.ibm/mobilefirst/6.3.0/server/wlp/usr/servers, I can see the Worklight folder.  It has an _analytics.war file in it (which is different from my Eclipse install which has a worklight-analytics.war and worklight-analytics-service.war)
And in the messages.log file, I am getting messages saying that the web application _analytics is available.
But I then a number of messages with
com.worklight.analytics.api.AnalyticsHttpService.sendDataToURL target server response code: 404

Going directly to `http://localhost:10080/_analytics` responds with an "Authorization failed" message.

**Update - Got it working**

I uninstalled the dev edition CLI and downloaded the CLI from Passport Advantage and installed it from there.  The analytics feature now seems to work.  Although the link to it is still not available in the top right of the console.
I don't know if it's a different install package, or an issue on my Mac that I inadvertently resolved, but the analytics feature is now working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was that the version you originally downloaded was not up-to-date.
This will be corrected soon.

Proper mechanisms will be put in place so that this will not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I downloaded and installed the publically available MobileFirst Platform 6.3 CLI from https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/install/#clui. I created a simple app which connects to the MFP server. 
Result: Analytics works without any problem.
So you do not have to buy the product just to use the CLI with analytics.